# Ajax xhr onload not being called within django app

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a Django app with user posts. I am trying to add a 'like' / voting system. I had done this through complete page refreshes through a redirect where the vote was made then redirected back to the same page with the new vote / like total updates. I then was reading about ajax and how I could update part of a page without a full reload.

```js
let up_vote = document.getElementById("up-vote").addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "{% url 'up-vote' %}", true);
    console.log(xhr);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        console.log("inside");

    };
    console.log("outside");
});
```

So far my js looks like this. When I click on "up-vote", "clicked" is printed along with the xhr object. However, `onload` appears to never be called as "inside" is never printed but instead passes straight over to "outside".

I have a feeling that the issue is to do with the URL path but I don't know how to get path properly.
The basic file structure of this app is:

```
app
|-static/app  
    |-scripts/*this js file*/  
    |-images  
    |-styles  
|-templates/app  
    |-html files
|-views.py *where the request is being made*
|-urls.py
```

urls.py contains,

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('post/<int:pk>/up/', up_vote, name='up-vote'),
    ...
]
```

and the views.py contain,

```
@login_required()
def up_vote(request, pk):
    print("HI")
    obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    uid = request.user.id
    if not obj.votes.exists(uid):
        obj.votes.up(uid)
    data = {
        'votes': obj.votes.count()
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Any help or advice greatly appreciated :)

p.s. I have also tried xhr.onreadystate which is what gives to the thought of the URL path being wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX request (as you might have guessed from its name), is asynchronous, so it will really pass straight to 'outside'.

In addition to that, you have to call `xhr.send()`

```
let up_vote = document.getElementById("up-vote").addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "{% url 'up-vote' %}", true);
    console.log(xhr);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        console.log("inside");
    };
    xhr.send()
    console.log("outside");
});
```

PS: I think your URL/views have issues. Your view and routes requires a `pk`, but your `{% url 'up-vote' %}` doesn't pass a `pk` to it

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to understand what was going on step by step so hadnt addedd `.send()` as i dint think it would get there but this makes more sense.